# How to get related entities into json?

Tags: json, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I have created three related entities for a survey: `Survey`, `Question` and `Options`.

```
class Question 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Survey", inversedBy="questions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $survey;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Options", mappedBy="Question")
     */
    private $options;
}

class Survey
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Question", mappedBy="Survey")
     */
    private $questions;
}

class Options
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Question", inversedBy="options")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $question;
}
```

I can make first query for a single `Survey` object. Then Doctrine makes a second query to retrieve the related `Question` objects.

```
public function showQuestions($id)
{
    $survey= $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Survey::class)
        ->find($id);

    $questions = $survey->getQuestions();
}
```

Then I can serialize result into a json using `symfony/serializer`.

```
{
 "survey": [
  {
   "questions": [
    {
     "name": "question1",
     "options": []
    }
  }
 ]
}
```

But I did not get the `Option` entity. Of course `Options` json object property is empty. How can I get it?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to serialize the entity? This may have something to do with max depth

Comment: Thank you! The issue was in groups definition.